# Replace a substring and optionally the subsequent character

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

How can I replace the character following a certain substring, if it is a `-`? I am using a regular expression to match and replace the substring itself, but I also want to match the character immediately following that if it is a hyphen.

For example :

```
$('.classg').on("click", function() {
    idq = $(this).attr('name');

    var _href = $('.classh').children("a").attr("href");

    $('.classh').children("a").attr("href", _href.replace(idq, ''));

    // ...
});
```

HTML:

```
<p class="classg"><a href="posting.php?topic_id=123456789">Answer</a></p>

<li class="classh" name="16992964">Multiquote</li>
```

After the replace of `idq`, I want to be able to determine what is the next character on the _href string just after the string `idq`. If the character is `-` then I want to replace it with `''` (the blank string). If it's something else, I want it to be ignored.

Comment: probably a good idea to post html please?

Comment: I will edit my post in few minutes and give more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `?` regex operator, which optionally matches the preceding element. If it is there, it will be replaced. If not, only the original ID is replaced.

Since the rest of your pattern is in a variable, you can construct the RegExp object like this: `var re = new RegExp(idq + "\\-?");`.

This matches the first occurrence of `idq`, optionally followed by a hyphen (`-`).

```
$('.classg').on("click", function() {
    var idq = $(this).attr('id'); // ID will be a number example : 998352

    var _href = $('.classh').children("a").attr("href");

    var re = new RegExp(idq + "\\-?");

    $('.classh').children("a").attr("href", _href.replace(re, ''));
});
```

Comment: YES :) Thanks it work just fine ! var re = new RegExp("\\-?" + idq) It was before I make mistake in my question thanks again !